# What is the behavior of a disowned process over SSH writing to stdout when the SSH session is lost?

Tags: ssh, stdout, disown

I have an application which processes HTTP requests, and it prints out certain information about the request as it processes it to `stdout`. In this scenario, I have run `disown -h` and `disown` on the process, after backgrounding it. It still continues to print to `stdout`, which is expected. Further, this process is started within an SSH session. Assume I have flaky internet access, and after doing all of the above, the connection is interrupted, without SSH being aware that this has occurred. Naturally, this takes a few moments before SSH is actually aware that the connection has interrupted.

During this time, the application starts to experience timeouts when processing requests, until the SSH session actually dies. Is this due to buffering issues involving its writing to `stdout` when the PTY no longer is exists?

Comment: If you're `disown`ing the process, it no longer cares about the terminal incorporated into your shell, so that *should* not be relevant to any issues.

Comment: That's what I had thought, too, but there definitely was erratic app behavior during the limbo where the SSH session was still alive despite being disconnected, so I was curious for the perspective of someone who has gone deep into the weeds of buffered I/O for terminals relative to PTYs.

Comment: Terminals are not incorporated into shells.  Are these HTTP requests going over the same flaky network connection that your SSH session is?

Answer (score 3):

`disown` will prevent your application from receiving a `SIGHUP` signal when SSH exits.  However, if the application subsequently writes to a pty that has been revoked, it will receive a `SIGPIPE` signal.  Unless you are handling or ignoring `SIGPIPE`, it will kill your application by default.

If the application does handle `SIGPIPE` then its attempts to write will return an error status, and then it's up to the application whether it ignores the error, aborts or does something else. (Ignoring errors is rarely wise.)

If you just want the easiest way to prevent your application from dying, and don't want to redirect it to a file, consider running it inside `screen`, or `tmux`, or else using `mosh` instead of `ssh`.